# How to improve typeAhead performance on xPage?

Tags: javascript, java, xpages

Here is my inputText control with typeAhead enabled:

```
<xp:inputText id="inputNameEditBox">
    <xp:typeAhead 
        mode="full" 
        minChars="3"        
        ignoreCase="true"
        valueList="#{javascript:return mytypeAheadList();}"
        var="searchValue" 
        valueMarkup="true" 
        id="typeAhead1">
    </xp:typeAhead>
</xp:inputText>
```

SSJS mytypeAheadList() function calls custom Java `userTools.userLookup()` function to get a set of suggestions. (Our server cannot access corporate directory so we have to use LDAP HTTP Java API).

SSJS library:

```
function mytypeAheadList(){
    var v=new userTools.userLookup();  //Java library
    var usrList = v.getUserList(searchValue);
    var lenList = usrList.length;
    var retList = "<ul>";

    if(lenList>0){
        for (var i=0; i<lenList; i++) { 
            var matchDetails:string = ["<li>",@Name("[ABBREVIATE]", @Left(usrList[i], "@")),"</li>"].join(""); 
            retList += matchDetails;
        }       
    } else {
        retList += ["<li>","None found","</li>"].join("");
    }

    retList += "</ul>"; 
    return retList;     
}
```

So that means `userTools` Java object is created each time user type a character. Is there a way to avoid it, e.g. make `var v` a global variable on page load? Seems scope variables cannot accept Java objects.

Comment: Is your Java object serializable?

Comment: No it's not serializable

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following:

1. Implement the *Serializable* interface to your POJO returned by *getUserLookup*. This allows to store the object in *viewScope*
2. Limit the max size of *lenlist*. E.g. 20 results would reduce the time of looping, the size of the HTTP response and the performance in the browser
3. Cache the result of the search (add *searchValue* and the resulting HTML string to a map). If a user hits backspace, the whole result must not be recomputed.
4. Drop SSJS. Use Java.
5. *optional*: If possible, precompute the results.

**EDIT**
Something like this:

```
function mytypeAheadList(){

    // check if value is already cached
    if( viewScope.containsKey("search~" + searchValue) ){
        return viewScope.get("search~" + searchValue);
    }

    // get the userLookup object
    var v = null;   
    if( viewScope.containsKey("userLookup") ){
        v = viewScope.get("userLookup");
    }else{
        v = new userTools.userLookup();
        viewScope.put("userLookup", v);
    }

    // if usrList is "unlimited", limit the max size
    var usrList = v.getUserList(searchValue);
    var lenList = usrList.length > 20 ? 20 : usrList.length;

    // if getUserList has a restriction parameter
    var usrList = v.getUserList(searchValue, 20);
    var lenList = usrList.length;

    // build the list
    var retList = null;

    // reuse a variable is up to 2 times faster
    var matchDetails = null;

    if(lenList>0){
        retList = "<ul>";
        for (var i=0; i<lenList; i++) { 
            // concatenating a string is up to 2 times faster then join
            matchDetails = "<li>" + @Name("[ABBREVIATE]", @Left(usrList[i], "@")) + "</li>";
            retList += matchDetails;
        }
        retList += "</ul>"; 
    } else {
        // why join a static string?
        retList = "<ul><li>None found</li></ul>";
    }


    // put the result to the cache
    viewScope.get("search~" + searchValue, retList);

    return retList;     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that.

Either you can put `var v` outside of your function to keep it loaded (and just lazy load it first time by checking if it is null).

Or you can put it all in a Java bean and let the scope of the bean determine how long you want to keep the data: ViewScope for just this page - ApplicationScope to allow all users to share it (and you can build in a check to force a maximum age of xx minutes - this could be relevant to consider if the data you look up could change).